# Blazor with css layout grid

Tags: css, border, css-grid, blazor

I am trying out web development and blazor for the first time. I am using the css layout style **display: grid**

I am making a component in Blazor that is going to be reusable, and I want to put a border around it, so I put a border in my css under the class that is my top level, the same level as my grid layout

```
.recipe-preview {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 9rem 3rem 24rem;
grid-template-rows: 9rem 9rem;
grid-template-areas: "image details details" "ingredients ingredients method";
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

but my right hand border is not aligning with the grid, but with the window itself.
[Image of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiVPA.png)

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display: inline-grid;
```

Know more here: [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: This didnt change anything